# How to translate "ASMR" to Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

> [Autonomous sensory meridian response (ASMR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_sensory_meridian_response) is a euphoric
> experience characterized by a static-like or tingling sensation on the
> skin that typically begins on the scalp and moves down the back of the
> neck and upper spine, precipitating relaxation.

As a personal experience, when I am listening to specific sounds (such as thoses in an ear massage, plastic crinkling and murmuring), I feel small intermittent touches behind the neck.

Many people register videos and sounds in order to induce "ASMR" to the listeners.

The origin of the "ASMR" effect is unclear, and the literal meaning of ASMR "Autonomous sensory meridian response" is not clear. The word ASMR is much more often than "Autonomous sensory meridian response", and many do not even know its meaning.

Answer (score 3):

Since the origin in unclear and the concept is new, I would introduce a new word for it based on the initialism. Following the model of [Aidoso](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aidoso), I would use the word *Asomoro*.

Comment: When I have looked for ASMR videos in other languages they seem to usually just call it *ASMR* as well, so this seems reasonable to me for everyday speech. As you mention, ASMR is a "new" concept, so you'd likely have to be explaining to your listener what it is no matter how you choose to name it. However, I think it would be worthwhile to also come up with an alternative name that has a more descriptive quality and isn't just based on these initials. Something like, *sensostimula sonaĵo* (just for example; I know it's not exactly matching the English term)